# App crashes on launch screen with no error log (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios9

I have an app. created on Xcode 6 which start crashing after opening it on Xcode 7. The app. crashes on Launch Screen at `main.m` file with no error log at all.

I tried to Edit Scheme to enable logging options with no success to get the error log (Product Menu > Scheme > Edit Scheme).

[image]

**App works fine if launched using Xcode 6**

**Stack Trace:**

> (     0   Watershade                          0x000a8545 -[AppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 88  1   UIKit
>   0x250b9469  + 280   2   UIKit
>   0x252ae515  + 2356  3   UIKit
>   0x252b0a49  + 1368  4   UIKit
>   0x252bb2f9  + 36    5   UIKit
>   0x252af2eb  + 130   6   FrontBoardServices
>   0x283200c9  + 12    7   CoreFoundation
>   0x21b70ffd  + 12    8   CoreFoundation
>   0x21b702c1  + 216   9   CoreFoundation
>   0x21b6ee1b  + 1714  10  CoreFoundation
>   0x21abbb31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476     11  CoreFoundation
>   0x21abb943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106   12  UIKit
>   0x250b3127  + 558
>
> 13  UIKit                               0x250adf21 UIApplicationMain
>   + 1440    14  Watershade                          0x000db865 main + 108   15  libdyld.dylib                       0x2f9b8aaf  + 2

Comment: Add a exception break point because this question and your description gives no chance tho give an actual answer :(

Comment: I did that. It only calls didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and then it crash with no logs!

Comment: So can you post a stack trace from that exception break point?

Comment: same project works in Xcode 6. maybe this is an issue in Xcode 7

Comment: yea it could be :) but still seems strange to me :)

Comment: @hasan83 you already have xcode 7? Mine is only xcode 6.4 when did you update that? I didn't see any updates in app store...

Comment: It's Xcode 7 beta. you download it from the apple developer website.